# Best practices for url extensions and rest services in the same app

Tags: jsp, rest, spring-mvc, servlets, httprequest

I am developing a web app which consists of an user's admin panel (users, roles, etc.) Until now, my url's are like this:

/myapp/admin/users --> Returns a view of the user's table
/myapp/admin/roles --> Returns a view of the role's table
..
..

And the requests that returns data, like this:
/myapp/admin/getRoles
/myapp/admin/getUser?username=xx

But I've recently developed a REST service and my mind has changed a little bit. I would like to include url's such as /users/username and so on.

Which is best practices to include url's which returns diferent type of data? (html views, json..)

Maybe including extensions like that?

/myapp/admin/users.jsp --> Returns a view of the user's table
/myapp/admin/users --> Returns a json with the users

Another thing that I don't undestand are the .go and .do extensions which so many people use.

I have the following view resolver:

```
<!-- Defining which view resolver to use -->
<bean class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" > 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
```

I request /myapp/admin/users.jsp but returns 404. This is my servlet-mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AdminPanel</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do I need to define the extension in the controller directly?

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/users.jsp") -->VIEW   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/users") -->DATA

Is that solution a best practice?

I will apreciate and vote all useful answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Extensions are a popular choice, but the RESTful way to do this is via `Content Negotiation`. The requester would put into the `Accept` header the formats that they can accept, such as `text/html` or `application/json`. The server would select one of the provided formats and return the response using that format.

Comment: and if it is a GET like /users/james you also include the application/json header? I mean that the json header is referred to send the data in json format or both (send and receive)?

Comment: The client requests with an Accept header. It can request multiple types with different priorities, as detailed in RFC 2616. The server responds with a Content-Type header indicating the format of the data that has been returned.